# Xpath returns null

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I need to scrape the price of this page: https://www.asos.com/monki/monki-lisa-cropped-vest-top-with-ruched-side-in-black/prd/23590636?colourwayid=60495910&cid=2623

However it is always returning null:

My code:

> 'price' :response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "current-price")]').get()

[image]

Can someone help please?

Thanks!

[image: code]

When Extracted using XHR:
[image]

How to retrieve price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the xpath, it's that the price is being retrieved with XHR.

If you use scrapy sheel and type view(response) you can see that the price is not being generated:
[image]

Look at the source of the original webpage and search for the price:
[image]

Then use this url the scrape the price:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        import re
        price_url = 'https://www.asos.com' + re.search(r'window.asos.pdp.config.stockPriceApiUrl = \'(.+)\'', response.text).group(1)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=price_url,
                             method='GET',
                             callback=self.parse_price,
                             headers=self.headers)

    def parse_price(self, response):
        import json
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)
        ...............
        ...............
        ...............
```

I couldn't get around 403 error with the headers I provided, but maybe you'll have more luck.

**Edit:**

In order to get the price from the json file there's actually no need for json.loads

```
    def parse_price(self, response):
        jsonresponse = response.json()[0]
        price = jsonresponse['productPrice']['current']['text']
        # You can also use jsonresponse.get() if you prefer
        print(price)
```

Output:

```
£10.00
```

Comment: Hi,

I tried your way using json and got a result as updated in my question.
Can you tell me how to retrieve the price from the json result now?

Thanks!

Comment: @Fazlul Really? How??

Answer (score 1):

This code that you've tried :

```
price' :response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "current-price")]').get()
```

looks like you have your own written methods from your framework, but in native Selenium-Python Binding I would do this :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, "current-price")]/span"))).text)
```

Comment: I have updated my question.

Can you please tell me how to add it to my yield? I'm new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XPath you have used is returning 2 different elements. Try the following xpath to get the price of the item

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-id='current-price']").text
```

Update:

```
price :response.xpath('//span[@data-id='current-price']').get()
```

Comment: Like this:

def parse(self, response):
            yield{
               'price': driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-id='current-price']").text
            } 

------Not working :(

Comment: what is the error? Updated my code.Try that

Comment: Unfortunately still null.