# Get price from XHR and Combine Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have to scrape data(name, price, description, brand,...) on this website: [https://www.asos.com/women/new-in/new-in-clothing/cat/?cid=2623&nlid=ww%7Cnew+in%7Cnew+products%7Cclothing](https://www.asos.com/women/new-in/new-in-clothing/cat/?cid=2623&nlid=ww%7Cnew%20in%7Cnew%20products%7Cclothing)

My code is as such:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class TestcrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testcrawl'

    def remove_characters(self,value):
        return value.strip('\n')

    allowed_domains = ['www.asos.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.asos.com/women/new-in/new-in-clothing/cat/?cid=2623&nlid=ww|new+in|new+products|clothing']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//article[@class='_2qG85dG']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
     Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='_39_qNys']")),
)


def parse_item(self, response):
    yield{
           'name':response.xpath("//div[@class='product-hero']/h1/text()").get(),
           'price':response.xpath("//span[@data-id='current-price']").get(),
           'description':response.xpath("//div[@class='product-description']/ul/li/text()").getall(),
           'about_me': response.xpath("//div[@class='about-me']//text()").getall(),
           'brand_description':response.xpath("//div[@class='brand-description']/p/text()").getall()
        }
```

However, due to javascript I cannot get the **Price**. I need to get it thorugh XHR.
My code for getting the price of only one item in the list is as followed:

```
import scrapy
import json


class AsosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'asos'
    allowed_domains = ['www.asos.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.asos.com/api/product/catalogue/v3/stockprice?productIds=200369183&store=ROW&currency=GBP&keyStoreDataversion=hnm9sjt-28']

                   
    def parse(self, response):
        #print(response.body)
        resp = json.loads(response.text)[0]
        price = resp.get('productPrice').get('current').get('text')
        print(price)
        yield {
            'price': price
```

Here, my start_urls is the Request URL. And it keeps changing for each item.

Item1: https://www.asos.com/api/product/catalogue/v3/stockprice?productIds=23443988&store=ROW&currency=GBP&keyStoreDataversion=hnm9sjt-28

Item2: https://www.asos.com/api/product/catalogue/v3/stockprice?productIds=22495685&store=ROW&currency=GBP&keyStoreDataversion=hnm9sjt-28

Only the productsIds are changing!!!

I need to insert the second code in the first code to get the price as well? How to do it please?

Thanks!

[pix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryAX5.png)

Comment: It looks like the `aria-label`s contain the prices - can't you just pull the price from there?

Answer (score 0):

items.py:

```
import scrapy

class AsosItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    about_me = scrapy.Field()
    brand_description = scrapy.Field()
```

As I said in you last post I have a problem with this website on my computer for some reason, but you need to do something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import AsosItem

class TestcrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testcrawl'

    allowed_domains = ['www.asos.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.asos.com/women/new-in/new-in-clothing/cat/?cid=2623&nlid=ww|new+in|new+products|clothing']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//article[@class='_2qG85dG']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='_39_qNys']")),
    )

    def remove_characters(self,value):
        return value.strip('\n')

    def parse_item(self, response):
        price_url = 'https://www.asos.com' + re.search(r'window.asos.pdp.config.stockPriceApiUrl = \'(.+)\'', response.text).group(1)

        item = AsosItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-hero']/h1/text()").get()
        item['description'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-description']/ul/li/text()").getall()
        item['about_me'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='about-me']//text()").getall()
        item['brand_description'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='brand-description']/p/text()").getall()

        request = scrapy.Request(url=price_url, callback=self.parse_price)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        return request

    def parse_price(self, response):
        jsonresponse = response.json()[0]
        price = jsonresponse['productPrice']['current']['text']
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['price'] = price
        return item
```

Test the code and if it doesn't work then get the general idea and tweak it a bit, I can't test it myself.

Comment: can you tell me what this line is?

`price_url = 'https://www.asos.com' + re.search(r'window.asos.pdp.config.stockPriceApiUrl = \'(.+)\'', response.text).group(1)`

Normally for the price I need the HTTP Request which I get from the Inspect.

Comment: This is the json file that contains the price, we get it with regex. Search for 'window.asos.pdp.config.stockPriceApiUrl' in the source of one of the products and navigate to that url to see it.

Comment: Where do you get this json file?

Comment: I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606403/xpath-returns-null)